# How do I get a list of a Tezos smart contract KT1 address entrypoints and its parameters?

Tags: node, smart-contracts, kt1, smartpy, query

I wish to retrieve info from a KT1 address so I know which entrypoints are available for consuming and which are their parameters and types. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

To find all the entrypoints and their types using `tezos-client` you can use the following command:

```
tezos-client get contract entrypoints for <src>
```

To check a specific entrypoint you can also use:

```
tezos-client  get contract entrypoint type of <entrypoint> for <src>
```

You can find more about [available commands in the official documentation](https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/cli-commands.html).

Answer (score 3):

The SmartPy contract explorer allows you to see all the entry point of a given contract in any of the networks (main and test) along with autogenerated forms to interact with all those entrypoints.

Example:

https://smartpy.io/test2/explore.html?address=KT1APXAZKofAtPsxFKPLbjMJohe1rXaGJoYc